# regex for matching a string into words but leaving multiple spaces

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

Here's what I expect. I have a string with numbers that need to be changed into letters (a kind of cipher) and spaces to move into different letter, and there is a tripple spaces that represent a space in output. For example, a string `"394 29 44 44   141 6"` will be decrypted into "Hell No".

```
function string.decrypt(self)
    local output = ""

    for i in self:gmatch("%S+") do
        for j, k in pairs(CODE) do
            output = output .. (i == j and k or "")
        end
    end

    return output
end
```

Even though it decrypts the numbers correctly I doesn't work with spacebars. So the string I used above decrypts into "HellNo", instead of expected "Hell No". How can I fix this?

Comment: `for i in self:gsub("  +", " 0 "):gmatch("%S+") do` and add zero as code for space `CODE["0"]=" "`

Comment: Interesting solution, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
CODE = {["394"] = "H", ["29"] = "e", ["44"] = "l", ["141"] = "N", ["6"] = "o"}
function replace(match)
    local ret = nil
    for i, v in pairs(CODE) do
        if i == match then
            ret = v
        end
    end
    return ret
end

function decrypt(s)
    return s:gsub("(%d+)%s?", replace):gsub("  ", " ")
end

print (decrypt("394 29 44 44   141 6"))
```

Output will contain `Hell No`. See the [Lua demo online](https://ideone.com/3i7pRv).

Here, `(%d+)%s?` in `s:gsub("(%d+)%s?", replace)` matches and captures one or more digits and just matches an optional whitespace (with `%s?`) and the captured value is passed to the `replace` function, where it is mapped to the char value in `CODE`. Then, all double spaces are replaced with a single space with `gsub("  ", " ")`.